# How can I type a typescript function which takes an array of objects as first argument and a specific property expected on the objects as argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `sortObjectsByDate( objects:any[], prop:string )` where I want to use the `prop` arguments to specify which property on the objects stored in the array is to be used for sorting and I would like to use type-checking so the `sortObjectsByDate` function only accepts an array of objects which have the `prop` property typed as a Date object.

If I call the function passing `[ {foo: new Date() }]` as the first argument and `"foo"` as the second I would expect no type error...

But I want a type error if I pass `[ {bar: new Date(), foo: "nope" }]` as the first argument and `"foo"` as the second because `[ {bar: new Date(),foo: "nope" }]` does not have a `foo` property that is a `Date`.

Comment: please share minimum reproducable example in TS playground

Comment: @captain-yossarian I don't think that's a good thing to ask. The rules on stack overflow is generally to *not* place part of the question on external sites. Instead, it's better to ask for a minimum reproducible sample on stack overflow (and maybe also a copy on TS playground)

Comment: @Evert, sure, I was't clear enough. Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygeQEYCsCm0yAQgJ4AiAhlPgDwDSi+AHjWACbIpRoxgDmAGkQAVJq3wcuAb0QBtANb5SiPonoBdAFyIqNRAF8AfAAo4eQlGQ6RcjcIAOaOA530AlImkAoRH8QA9AGIAHRh3gbe3kGIAOroCtbeqBg4BERkevgmcl6I2JRoOmD4AO661NmeBoj2iABEBWj17gDcUTEAomjORaKkDviIAOTIPHz8w6pcYHBQiJTIyDD8YJTYADZDUHCIUANDw1nDISYATADMZ2fuyehYFhkUlTl5TcVlFTQm7sLAcHAdPVZoN6oZasJ6v84C12kA)

```
function sortObjectsByDate
    <K extends string, T extends { [key in K]: Date }>
    (objects: T[], prop: K)
{
    // ...
}
```

Whenever you need to relate something between types you'll need to use generic parameters. Here `K` is the key string, and then `T` can be any type which has `K: Date`.

```
// Works:
sortObjectsByDate([ { bar: new Date() } ], "bar");

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.(2322)
sortObjectsByDate([ { bar: new Date(), foo: "nope" } ], "foo");
```

Comment: Thank you, I was nearing this solution but the generic type syntax is still a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

Below should fit your purpose

```typescript
sortObjectsByDate(dates: { [key: string]: Date }[], key: string) {}
```

Below shows above implementation. TS throws error

[image]

[See this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v2hfvk)